# Minimal files needed to deploy ASP.NET App to the Web Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a ASP.NET project. When compiling this project it will create a DLL.

Let's assume this project does not need any other dlls(references).

I want to know what are the minimal files needed.

I know VB code behind files will be part of this dll and are not needed on server

So question is:

```
1: Is Web.Config file needed?
2: Is Global.asax needed?
3: Are aspx files needed?
```

If all of above needed then can't we simply copy them to the we server and don't publish the application?

Comment: Why _not_ publish the application? It knows which files are needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can `xcopy` your `web.config`, `global.asax` and all `.aspx` files to the server, which is essentially what the `Publish` command in Visual Studio does.

There is also the option to create a new `Profile` when doing a `Publish` via Visual Studio and have the files published to a directory so you can see what would have been pushed to an actual server before actually doing it. I use this as part of our deployment process to have a copy of the code that gets deployed to each of our testing environments.

Comment: Personally, I always publish a release to a file server, in the relevant version directory, and then upload this to the production server - As said, you can then see what the app needs, and only upload changes if you're being particular or upload the lot. You also then have a static build of that version (rather than dipping into Source Control)

Comment: @Karl Anderson: How about the main dll(Web project) it should be xpoied too?

Comment: @SNash - Yes, the web project DLL should be `xcopy`'d as well. Everything you need for your application to run on a fresh, pristine environment should be part of your `xcopy`/`Publish` deployment. As a side note, I backup and then blow away whatever was in the environment I am updating to ensure the deployment process works. Note: Take care to notice if you are building in `Debug` or `Release`, I have worked in some places where testing environments use `Debug` builds, while others where everything beyond the developer's machines is `Release` mode.

Comment: Fair Enough.  That's all I need to know.